# Android - Set textview when click item

Tags: android, gridview, textview

I have a gridview and each item have a text view.
i would like SetText for text view when i click a item in gridview.

it's method: `setOnItemClickListener`

but I don't know how to control the textview.

any ideas, examples or tutorials?
thanks.

Comment: simply use textview.setTExt(); inside  setOnItemClickListener

I guess this is what you wanted

Comment: Check [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/custom-gridview.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inflate the textview from layout file to a TextView instance. Then, just set text to it as below:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.this_is_the_id_of_textview);
text.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the `click event` of the TextView inside the `getView` method. If it will click then just change the text.

**Edit**

```
...getView(...) {
  TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.this_is_the_id_of_textview);
  text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // TextView was clicked!
      // Change the text
   }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just try this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    TextView textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview);
    textview.setText("write your text here");
}
```

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya what you have edited? is something wrong i wrote?

Answer (score -1):

let's say you have 4 grid :

```
String[] subtitle = {"Hotel", "Store","Restaurant","Station"};
```

set onItemClick for gridview :

```
GridView gView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            TextView ket =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
            ket.setText(subtitle [position]);
               }
            });
```

so, if you press / onclick in image grid the result will show array string based on position.

Comment: your code don't run, because textview is defined in custom adapter not in gridview